# Google Cloud SQL Storage Expanding Issue

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My PostgreSQL database storage is expanding way too much relative to my real database storage. I am assuming it is making logs for every actions against the database. If so, how do I turn it off?

[image]

All tables' storage size in the database:

```
   table_name    | pg_size_pretty 
-----------------+----------------
 matches         | 3442 MB
 temp_matches    | 3016 MB
 rankings        | 262 MB
 atp_matches     | 41 MB
 players         | 11 MB
 injuries        | 4648 kB
 tournaments     | 1936 kB
 temp_prematches | 112 kB
 locations       | 104 kB
 countries       | 16 kB
(10 rows)
```

My storage usage should be around 10GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PostgreSQL instance may have Point-in-time recovery (PITR) enabled.

To add explanation, [PITR uses write ahead logs (WAL)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage). It is necessary to archive the WAL files for instances it is enabled on. This archiving is done automatically on the backend and will consume storage space (even if the instance is idle) and therefore using this feature would result on an increased storage space on your DB instance.

Here's a similar issue: [Google Cloud SQL - Postgresql storage keeps growing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013896/google-cloud-sql-postgresql-storage-keeps-growing)

You can stop the storage increase by disabling Point-in-time recovery: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr#disablingpitr

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you verify if you have set the value "**[Enable automatic storage increases](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings)**" since your instance's storage will continue increasing and your pocket will be affected.

Please keep in mind that you can increase storage size, but you cannot decrease it; the storage increases are permanent for the life of the instance. When you enable this setting, a spike in storage requirements can permanently increase storage costs (incrementally) for your instance.

On the other hand, If you have the Point-in-time recovery ( [PITR](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage) ) enabled, I recommend you disable it in order to delete the logs. If not, I think that It would be necessary contact the GCP support team in order that they inspect your instance carefully.